# How to create a rounded rectangle with thickness and an image inside it in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I' using Juan Mendes logic (http://js-bits.blogspot.in/2010/07/canvas-rounded-corner-rectangles.html) to create a rectangle with rounded corners. However I wanted to add thickness to it. So i tried adding

```
ctx.lineWidth
```

Upon adding linewidth even though I get the thickness the rounded corners are gone.

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/cZ2gH/

Also how can I draw an image inside the rectangle with image borders being rounded off as well ?

Comment: I've found way to do it http://jsfiddle.net/6ja7Y/14 . Would this be the best approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what clipping windows are for.  The idea is: create a path, call `ctx.clip()`, and all subsequent drawing operations won't affect anything outside the path.

I'm not sure what the problem you had with thick lines was.  After playing around a bit I settled on the following approach:
1) draw the image clipped to a roundrect; 2) draw the same roundrect with thick lines on top of it.

(Other things I tried such as drawing a filled roundrect and clipping the image to a smaller roundrect inside didn't work as well.)

Jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cZ2gH/1/).

Also: this is straightforward in CSS3.  Unless you need the level of control you get with canvas, you might want to try doing it declaratively (CSS fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FEQuu/)).

Answer (score 1):

### Composite method

You can simply use composite modes for this if canvas is required (or I would recommend CSS3 and `border-radius` as in the other answer).

**[Live demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/puHEV/)**

```
var rect = [20, 20, 300, 300],
    cr = 25;            // corner radius
```

Now create a rounded rectangle path:

```
var pi = Math.PI,       // cache it here to make code more readable
    x1 = rect[0],       // cache points
    y1 = rect[1],
    x2 = rect[2] + x1,
    y2 = rect[3] + y1;

// create a rounded rectangle path
ctx.beginPath();

ctx.arc(x1 + cr, y1 + cr, cr, pi, 1.5 * pi);  // upper left corner
ctx.arc(x2 - cr, y1 + cr, cr, 1.5 * pi, 0);   // upper right corner
ctx.arc(x2 - cr, y2 - cr, cr, 0, 0.5 * pi);   // lower right corner
ctx.arc(x1 + cr, y2 - cr, cr, 0.5 * pi, pi);  // lower left corner

ctx.closePath();
```

Now we have a path for the rounded rectangle. Next thing we need to do is to make a solid color in it so we can use this for composite mode - we just use default fill color here:

```
ctx.fill();
```

Now we can set composite mode to say that next thing drawn should be drawn atop of what we have (solid pixels):

```
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';

// draw in image
ctx.drawImage(img, x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
```

Then we reset the composite mode so we can draw as normal (this is faster and less costly than using save/restore):

```
ctx.globalCompositeMode = 'source-over';  /// default composite mode

// draw a thick border    
ctx.lineWidth = 20;
ctx.stroke();
```

### Drawbacks and benefits with composite mode versus clipping.

The other way is to use `clip()` on the path but be aware of that clipping will force you to use `save()`/`restore()` as there is no clean way to reset clipping at this time (it may be fixed in the future). save/restore is a costly operation as it stores *all* settings onto the stack and needs to pop *all* settings back when restoring.

If you stroke your path without first removing the clipping the stroke will be cut in half.

For composite the drawback is if you have other content already drawn into the background behind the new image. To solve you would need to use an off-screen canvas to do this operation and then draw the result from that into the main canvas.