# Canvas "Pong" game paddles

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

As part of my studies i'm modifying some parts in an open-sourced "Pong" game I found online (created by [Kushagra Agarwal](http://cssdeck.com/user/kushsolitary)).

**[Game's Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XLKFC/1/)**

**I'm trying to set a nicer look to the paddles:**

1. Achieve rounded corners instead of sharp edges.
   I found **[this article](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-rounded-corners/)**, but I don't know how to implement it to my code.
   Right now those are the paddles :

   ```
   function Paddle(pos) {
   // Height and width
   this.h = 30;
   this.w = 600;

   // Paddle's position
   this.x = W / 2 - this.w / 2;
   this.y = (pos == "top") ? 0 : H - this.h;
   }
   ```
2. Suggestions about using an actual image instead of just color filled paddles (or a reference to an article about that subject).

Thanks,
Roy

Comment: You're looking in the wrong chunk of code. You need to look at the `draw()` function. The function loops through the paddles and draws them, currently just `fillRect`. Depending on the style you're after you could just draw a circle at both ends of the paddle to get a rounded corner look. Check out http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp for some examples of the different Canvas fill and draw commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your pads are slim and sleek you can take advantage of the low room for space and draw two rectangles on top of each other instead of using arcs etc. to create the illusion of roundness. Slightly offset the second rectangle, and since we use two it may be more efficient to add both to a path and fill them at the same time:

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/XLKFC/15/)**

```
function draw() {
    paintCanvas();
    for(var i = 0; i < paddles.length; i++) {
        p = paddles[i];

        ctx.beginPath();                       // begin new path
        ctx.rect(p.x, p.y, p.w, p.h);          // main rect.
        ctx.rect(p.x-1, p.y+1, p.w+2, p.h-2);  // second, giving the round illus.
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.fill();                            // fill at the same time
    }

    ball.draw();
    update();
}
```

If you want something more complex you will benefit from first drawing it to an off-screen canvas, then `drawImage()` that canvas to your game screen (you can also do this with shown approach). But for this kind of game it is probably not worth the extra effort.

**[Here is an effective way of creating rounded rectangles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743250/how-to-create-a-rounded-rectangle-with-thickness-and-an-image-inside-it-in-canva/19745956#19745956)** (if you need a thicker pad).

I would rather spend more time optimizing the `fillStyle` so you can share the same fill style when drawing the ball and the pads as this is an expensive operation. You could also set the CSS background color to blue instead of filling canvas, then use `clearRect()` to clear it (not having to set `fillStyle` more than once).

Hope this helps!